# How to create a dynamic chart using ember-vega

Tags: ember.js, vega, orbit.js

Im trying to create a vega chart in an ember octane app but in doing so im able to render the chart once, but from then on, even if the values change, the chart doesn't get rerendered

the code im using is

component.ts

```
@tracked
  model!: any;

get chartData() {
    const data = this.model.data;
    return {
      table: data.map((datum: any) => {
        return {
          ...datum
        };
      })
    };
  }
```

chart.hbs

```
{{vega-vis spec=this.spec data=this.chartData}}
```

why isn't it not working, but at the same time
doing `set(this,"dataSource",this.model.data)` works

```
dataSource: computed(function() {
    return emberArray([
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
    ]);
}),

data: computed('dataSource.{[],@each.amount}', function () {
    const dataSource = get(this, 'dataSource');
    return {
        table: dataSource.map((datum) => {
            // return a copy because Vega Vis will mutate the dataset.
            return {
                ...datum
            };
        })
    };
})
```

Comment: I guess either the computed property is not recomputed or the object / array used as `@model` argument is not replaced by mutated.